# problema con java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

Estoy realizando un programa con `JRadioButton`. Tengo un arreglo de `JRadioButton` y a cada botón le quiero asignar un nombre que va a tomar de un arreglo de `String`. Lo estoy realizando con dos ciclos `for`. Uno que recorre el arreglo de los botones y otro que recorre el arreglo de los `String`. Pero me da una excepción  `java.lang.NullPointerException`. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal. Dejo lo que llevo:

```
    public class Radio_But {

        private String[] carreras;
        private ButtonGroup[] grupoD;
    }
    public Radio_But() {
        carreras = new String[5];
        opciones = new JRadioButton[5];
    }
    public void atributos() {

        String[] carreras = {"Sistemas", "Industrial", "Logistica", "Gestion", "Tics"};
        for (int i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < carreras.length; j++) {
                opciones[i].setText(carreras[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

cuando haces  new JRadioButton[5]; solo estas creando el arreglo pero esta vacío trata de llenarlo antes de entrar a tu for o mejor quita tu for y pon este para llenar las opciones con las carreras

```
String[] carreras = {"Sistemas", "Industrial", "Logistica", "Gestion", "Tics"};
        for (int i = 0; i < carreras.length; i++) {
            opciones[i] = new JRadioButton(carreras[i]);    
        }
```

Comment: Una explicación de que modificaste que nos ayude a comprender tu solución no le vendría mal

Comment: y como es que llenaria mi JRadioButton[5] antes de entrar al for por favor necesito ayuda

Comment: Actualice la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Tu primer problema es la longitud del arreglo, dado que arreglo de longitud 5, hace un indexado de 0 a 4 campos.

```java
String[] carreras = {"Sistemas", "Industrial", "Logistica", "Gestion", "Tics"};
System.out.print(carreas[0]); // sistemas
System.out.print(carreas[4]); // Tics
```

Por lo tanto tu ciclo `for` debe ir de `0` a `carreras.length-1`, además **no es necesario** el doble ciclo `for` para lograr lo que deseas, dado que `carreras[0]` debe ir contenido en `opciones[0]` osea la misma posición. (*el mismo valor en i*)

```java
public class Radio_But {
    private String[] carreras;
    private ButtonGroup[] grupoD;
    private int max_opciones = 5;

  public Radio_But() {
    carreras = new String[max_opciones ];
    opciones = new JRadioButton[max_opciones ];
  }

  public void atributos() {
    String[] carreras = {"Sistemas", "Industrial", "Logistica", "Gestion", "Tics"};
    for (int i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
        // crear boton y asignar texto
        JRadioButton el_boton=new JRadioButton(carreas[i]);
        // la posición en la pantalla
        el_boton.setBounds(10,i*30,100,24); 
        // agregar a opciones 
        opciones[i] = el_boton;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Diego Mesa disculpa hice lo que me recomendaste que es darle una longitu de 5 a mis arreglos de carreras y opciones y dejar solamente un for pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Debes recordar llenar con `Valores` a tus array de `opciones`, asi como dices  `carreras = {"", "",""}` debes meter objetos de tipo `JRadioButton` en opciones. ( favor comenta si ese no el problema)

Comment: una pegunta como meto esos objetos de tipo JRadioButton en opciones no logro entender esa parte

Comment: Existen dos formas, pero primero ¿esta usando un editor de codigo https://netbeans.org/ o https://www.eclipse.org/? ,  o ¿esta programando en algun otro editor?

Comment: estoy usando netbeans.org

Comment: He actualizado el codigo, pero te recomiendo seguir este tutorial para aclarar mejor tus dudas  https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=112&punto=&inicio=20

Comment: y si requieras obtener valor por evento click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883604/listening-on-buttongroup-for-child-changes-and-print-selected-jradiobuttons.